# WPF C# draw smooth rectangles on mouse move without lacking with Black outer area

Tags: c#, wpf

I am drawing rectangles for screen captures but when I draw it on mouse move it looks like it lacking and following mouse and not drawing smoothly.

[image]

But I want Drawing with smoothness

[image]

My code:
I have four rectangles and when I started drawing I give them margins between them and show our selected area in original color.
But when we remove outer four rectangles which make black area(outside of the rectangles) it works fast from before but I also want black outer areas as well.

My Code for outer rects:

```
rect_topleft.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
rect_topleft.Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, h - sY);
rect_bottomleft.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
rect_bottomleft.Margin = new Thickness(0, startY, w - startX, -25);
rect_bottomright.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
rect_bottomright.Margin = new Thickness(startX, endY, pictureBox2.Width - endX, 0); //Here picturebox2 is grid
rect_topright.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
rect_topright.Margin = new Thickness(endX, startY, 0, -25);
```

**EDIT:-**

**After Using Clemens Code :**
[image]
it works fine on seperate project as shown in answer but it still lag in my code when i integrate it 

**Any solution for my code or any other method for doing this :**

Comment: my code means just on mouse move and resize it with rectangles . In edit I show my code just a transparent background pic and draw on it and resizing after mouse up .

Comment: I just need a light code which run without lag on normal systems also

Comment: actually I am making a screen capturing software. first I draw a rectangle of white area and then I get capture the screen

Comment: @Clemens in my I have white and black area . how to get white area and black area height widths etc ? thanks

Comment: @Clemens why u removed your Answer ?

Comment: Can you share the Clemen's code? I guess it's removed